# CartoDB geom (coordinates) join: without exact match

Tags: carto, sql, geography, attribute-joins

Trying to join two datasets (layers) on CartoDB based on their geographical fields (in CartoDB's the_geom created field). However, the basic ST_Intersection function does not work since its tolerance is too small and these coordinates are off by more than 0.00000001. Is there another function to do this? (Trying to join based on approximate coordinates).

Comment: This is already answered [in another place](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cartodb/V7BHVKgxgaE).